# No owin.Environment item was found in the context when creating user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin

### Scenario:

I have a class library project. Which has all the required DLL's for owin security.
I am using this class library project in a web project.
I am creating, adding roles (all sort of user management) in the class library project and the vision is to re-use this project in multiple web project.
I made startup class in the class library project and also made other thing that is required. for ex: identitymodel
App.config has the key

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="namespace.Startup, assembly" />
  <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup " value="false" />

</appSettings>
```

### Problem:

When I try to create user, I am having this error:

```
no owin.environment item was found in the context
```

Any idea how to fix that??